# How can I fix a missing user in SharePoint?

Tags: user, restore

I have a SharePoint Online (O365) site that has a Document Library called 'Project Documents'. When I try to access it via REST using the following URL I get an error:

```
 https://{Site}/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Project Documents')
```

The error is:

> User cannot be found.

If I look up the author id for this document library, it is Id 11.

I cannot find a user in my SharePoint with an Id of 11.

So it appears that the author of the Document library no longer exists and I don't know how to fix this issue. Is it possible to somehow recreate a user on id 11? Or can I find out the user details stored to Id 11?

The easiest way to fix this - except i have no idea how to do it! would be to simply change the Author property of the Document library to another user Id. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: are you able to see this document via browser?

Comment: I can see the Document Library via a browser. I need to either change the Author of the document library, or restore the User with id 11.

Comment: Why can you just update the document so it comes under your name. Then revert the change so the author will hold a valid value.

Comment: I'm not talking about a document, i'm talking about a document library.

Comment: Try to export the library as template with contents and recreate it.

Comment: Try the Rest Query with $select with the required properties